# NonGeneric Factory Method returning generic type

Tags: c#, class, generics

I get some data objects in an IEnumerable. The dataobjects can be of various types. Let's call them:

```
IEnumerable<BaseData>   

BaseData can be:
AData:BaseData 
BData:BaseData
```

I need to create wrapper classes to provide AData and BData specific features in addition to methods that can be run on just BaseData.

I decided to solve this by implementing a BaseWrapper class

```
AWrapper:BaseWrapper and 
BWrapper:BaseWrapper
```

.....mirroring the structure of the AData, BData and BaseData.

Declaring BaseWrapper is pretty straightforward:

```
public abstract class BaseWrapper<T> where T:BaseData
{
     protected T inner;
     // Additional methods consuming "inner" as BaseData.
}

public class AWrapper : BaseWrapper<AData>
{
       //Consuming "inner" variable here strongly typed as AData
}

public class BWrapper : BaseWrapper<BData>
{
       //Consuming "inner" variable here strongly typed as BData
}
```

However, how do I create a static factory method to allow the consumer of my Library to write this:

var wrappedEnumerable = EnumerableBaseData.Select(dt=>BaseData.Create(dt));

I would have thought that I could do this:

```
public static BaseWrapper Create(BaseData inner)
{
   if (inner is AData adata)
   {
        return new AWrapper(adata);
   }
   if (inner is BData bdata)
   {
        return new BWrapper(bdata);
   }
// And so on....
}
```

But the return type of the **Create method demands a generic parameter**.
The consumer of the method should not have to specify the type parameter.
A nongeneric BaseWrapper class as a base class for BaseWrapper (of T) does not really make sense because it has no functionality without access to BaseData object.

Comment: Can you at least post code that compiles (up to the point where you are stuck of course). For example, what is `WrapperBase`?

Comment: Where did the `WrapperBase` type suddenly appear from? Did you mean to type `BaseWrapper`?

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes, typo. I meant BaseWrapper.

Comment: @DavidG. The point is that the code that makes sense to me doesn't compile. I will try to make it clearer by emphasizing the point of interest.

Comment: Actually, the first code block could have been made actual code too, it helps people who want to run it to debug. Anyway, why not make `BaseWrapper<T>` implement a common interface, say `IBaseWrapper` and return that instead.

Comment: Yes. You're right. I should have made the external DTOs represented as compileable code. This would've pinpointed the pain point. Maybe I should go to the meta site and ask if it would be possible to indicate that code blocks were part of the same sample so that people only had to do a single copy into their IDE even if the post has a lot of words in between the various blocks.

Answer (score 0):

The following code compiles:

```
public class BaseData
{ }

public class AData : BaseData
{ }

public class BData : BaseData
{ }

public abstract class BaseWrapper
{

}
public abstract class BaseWrapper<T> : BaseWrapper where T : BaseData
{
    protected T inner;

    public BaseWrapper(T data)
    {
        inner = data;
    }

    // Additional methods consuming "inner" as BaseData.

    public static BaseWrapper Create(BaseData inner)
    {
       if (inner is AData)
       {
            return new AWrapper((AData)inner);
       }
       if (inner is BData)
       {
            return new BWrapper((BData)inner);
       }
    // And so on....
       return null;
    }
}

public class AWrapper : BaseWrapper<AData>
{
    //Consuming "inner" variable here strongly typed as AData
    public AWrapper(AData data) : base(data)
    {
    }
}

public class BWrapper : BaseWrapper<BData>
{
    //Consuming "inner" variable here strongly typed as BData
    public BWrapper(BData data) : base(data)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Hm. Yes, that was the one I described in the last paragraph of OP about creating a non generic base class as base class of the generic one. Of course, it will polymorphically invoke the methods of the generic sub class, which will have access to strongly typed BaseData. Maybe I am being too hung up on generics and should just accept that AWrapper will have both a BaseData and an AData private fields. Or the AData can be a private getter that is just downcasting BaseData into AData on the fly.

Comment: To be honest, I don't know how using a code such as the one in my answer will help you in any way, since either way you will not have access to derived classes properties or methods unless returning a generic `BaseWrapper` from the `Create` method, or casting the results back to the wrapper type you need.

Comment: Yeah. I just thought that the problem would be common. Extending upon a third party structure with a equivalent co-variant wrapper structure seems something that many would be faced with. The need for such a base class just to satisfy the compiler was to me a red flag that I was off to a bad start.

Comment: Perhaps there is another way to attack the problem, using extension methods instead of derived classes, and a static class to create "extension" properties. Then you don't need to deal with derived classes at all.

Comment: Yes, it is a good thought. It would automatically help me retain the structure because it would just be the AData and BData classes. Unfortunately, the extra methods does require additional data and there is need to encapsulate the DTOs to hide setters/getters.